# iOS: "cannot find interface declaration" error in Project-Swift header file

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I have class AViewController in a framework, written in Swift. Class A is a base class of UIViewController. My project uses this framework and class BViewController is a base class of AViewController.

In my Project-Swift.h file i receive an error in the declaration of BViewController. The error states that AViewController is not found. It seems that i need to include Framework-Swift.h in Project-Swift.h or a similar solution, but i am not sure how.

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you made any progress here?

Comment: Have you fixed it?